# How to publish current framework as cocoapods without creating a new one?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have hard time in publishing current framework to cocoaPods.... I found that in order to publish framework you need to run **pod lib create**. However, that creates completely new project, while I want to publish **my current framework**... How can I distribute my library without creating **new project and copying all files** and double checking git and etc...

Answer (score 1):

Create a podspec describing your framework. See the podspec manual at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html.

BTW, CocoaPods never uses existing Xcode projects for libraries.  CocoaPods creates a new workspace for CocoaPods consumers that combines their existing project into an Xcode workspace with the requested CocoaPods.

Comment: Beusterian so then I run pod lib create [pod name] it creates new workspace but uses my current project  also?

Comment: Nope, pod lib create creates a new development environment from scratch.  If you're not familiar with CocoaPods, it can be a good way to start - get the template library working and then replace the template with your library.

Comment: I have tried to build new project and get one error.. after running command pod lib lint with --no-clean I get this error:
NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass